# Which AI models can be converted to ONNX?

Tags: tensorflow, onnx, tf2onnx

I think in theory, every (TensorFlow) model can be converted to [ONNX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Neural_Network_Exchange) because at some level it is a pretty basic neural network graph.
Is this assumption correct?

But I found that there are limitations in practice.
For instance, I found that the conversion of [this model](https://tfhub.dev/google/lite-model/spice/1) to ONNX fails when using [tf2onnx](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx/issues/2155) (v1.14.0) with the following error message:

```
ValueError: make_sure failure: Current implementation of RFFT or FFT only allows ComplexAbs as consumer not {'Imag', 'Real'}
2023-04-04 09:30:26,364 - ERROR - Tensorflow op [Real: Real] is not supported
2023-04-04 09:30:26,364 - ERROR - Tensorflow op [Imag_5: Imag] is not supported
```

Questions:

- Is it possible to simplify above model (and models in general) such that it can be converted to ONNX?
- Can a pretrained model (e.g. from TensorFlow Hub) be simplified or is its original training data necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting models in ONNX isn't as straightforward as you think. And as @oleg-kostromin specified it depends if all the operators in your original framework have an equivalent in ONNX. I recommend changing the `opset` [see here](https://onnx.ai/sklearn-onnx/auto_tutorial/plot_cbegin_opset.html) to a higher version during conversion, and see if that resolves the issue. Otherwise, you can either remove the layers that are causing the conversion errors manually using graph-surgeon or write your own operator.

Answer (score 3):

In principle any model can be converted to onnx as long as it can be represented by the available [ONNX operators](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/docs/Operators.md). However, this is not always the case.

If you are using onnxruntime for inference, it is actually possible to create and register custom operators using either C++ or Python.

https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/reference/operators/add-custom-op.html

https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-extensions/blob/main/tutorials/tf2onnx_custom_ops_tutorial.ipynb